# Connection refused error due to timeout

Tags: python, json, server, nlp

```
  File "/home/abhigenie92/stanford2/Code/dependencies.py", line 18, in get_dependencies
    result = loads(server.parse(sentence));
  File "/home/abhigenie92/stanford-corenlp-python/jsonrpc.py", line 934, in __call__
    return self.__req(self.__name, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/abhigenie92/stanford-corenlp-python/jsonrpc.py", line 906, in __req
    raise RPCTransportError(err)
jsonrpc.RPCTransportError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The issue raised here also https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python/issues/13. The github link https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python. But it resolved, with the development and issues resolution being inactive, I asking this here.

```
Code:
import sys,imp

jsonrpc=imp.load_source('jsonrpc', '/home/abhigenie92/stanford-corenlp-python/jsonrpc.py')
import pdb,jsonrpc
from pprint import pprint
from simplejson import loads
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

      server = jsonrpc.ServerProxy(jsonrpc.JsonRpc20(),jsonrpc.TransportTcpIp(addr=("127.0.0.1", 8080)))
        sentences=sent_tokenize(full_text);print len(sentences)
        for index,sentence in enumerate(sentences):
            #try:
            result = loads(server.parse(sentence));
```

I have tried the solutions there but since the timeout issue persisted.

Answer (score 1):

A "Connection refused error due to timeout" means you tried to connect too many times and exceeded a limit.

I also used a GitHub API. It permits me to set a limitation like this to my request API.

If you want unlimited requests, create a token and use the authentication process of Github.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you give an example if possible.

Comment: I attempted to fix the English in this answer, but had to guess in a couple of places. Please review especially the middle paragraph. Thanks.